# How can I use micrometer.io with kotlin(non Spring project)

Tags: kotlin, micrometer

I'm trying to use Micrometer application in a Kotlin project(non-spring) but a bit confused how can. I use it. Any helps will be really appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Micrometer can be used standalone on the JVM,
here’s how to add to your project: https://micrometer.io/docs/installing
and here’s how to use it: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts